# What is the time-complexity of this nested for loop?

Tags: python, big-o, time-complexity

I have the following code in python:

```
def mystery(n):
    if n <= 50 :
        for i in range(n) :
            for j in range(n) :
                print i*j
    else :
        mystery(n-1)
```

For the following nested for loop:

```
for i in range(n) :
    for j in range(n) :
```

For every `i` in `n`, `j` iterates through `n` as many as `i` times. So shouldn't the complexity be `O(n^2)`? However, my peers tell me it is not, can someone provide an explanation as to why?

Comment: if `n<=50` its `O(n^2)` !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those loops are only executed when `n <= 50`, so they're just a concise description of a nontrivial but constant amount of work. At most 2500 `print` statements are executed. 2500, like any constant, is irrelevant for asymptotic complexity. Only the behavior in the limit (i.e. as n grows without bound) is important.

For larger n, the function just counts down from n down to 50. That part takes O(n) time, hence the time complexity of `mystery` as a whole is linear.

Comment: This is pretty much what I've been told, but I'm getting conflicting answers, how do I decided which is correct?

Comment: **please** include that Big-O is dealing with large values of `n`! Dear lord, this other answer -.-

Comment: So, I guess if there was no if statement (ignoring the recursive part), then the function would be `O(n^2)`?